# Poll gps strength every few minutes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

All, 
I have a requirement in our app to update the GPS strength every few minutes. I believe I've figured out how to do this with the Geolocator Plugin. However it's the "every few minutes" that's giving me trouble. I could use a Timer however from what I'm reading, iOS will kill your app if you don't do backgrounding properly:

https://www.jimbobbennett.io/timers-backgrounding/

What's the proper way to execute a method periodically in Xamarin that Android and iOS will be ok with?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to rely on the system native background operation modes.

For iOS: start reading the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) here and implement using the Xamarin counterparts

For Android: start reading the [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html) here and implement using the Xamarin counterparts

There might be a plugin or component available that abstracts thats away from you but it wouldn't hurt to know about each specifics.

Comment: Maybe not an answer but was very useful and let me to the solution which was as the documentation described.